# Can I use the new project format with .net 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a website that was written with .net 4.5.2. and MVC 5.

I want to keep it at that framework version, as the 3rd party libraries it uses have not yet been updated to use .net 5.

However, I like the new project structure.  Is it possible to convert the existing project over to the new project structure, or to create a project from scratch and add the older .net framework to it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this:

1. Create a new empty project with the new structure.
2. Edit the "frameworks" section of project.json:

   "frameworks": {
            "net452": { }
      }
3. Use Nuget to add MVC and the other libraries. (Not the Add reference Dialog as with the old project style.)